# Angularjs History back button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been looking at loads of examples for the Angularjs Back Button event, but none of the examples have been working out for me. Whenever the browser back button is pressed, my code does not get the event. I have been scratching my head for days now.

All I want to do is getting an alert asking if the user is sure that they want to go back and loose all their data.

Below is the code that I have been trying. It is a copy from other examples, but with complete code.

I have tried to add the $on in the controller using the $scope instead of $rootscope, I have tried watch on routechangestart, nothing seem to catch the back button.

Does someone have a complete small example or tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var BackButtonTest = angular.module('BackButtonTest', ['ngRoute']);

BackButtonTest.controller('backbuttonCtrl', function($scope, $location, $route) {
});

BackButtonTest.run(function($rootScope, $route, $location){
    //Bind the $locationChangeSuccess event on the //rootScope, so that we don't need to 
    //bind in induvidual controllers.

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
    });

    $rootScope.$watch(function () {
        return $location.path()
    }, function (newLocation) {
        if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
        // run a function or perform a reload
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML code I have used is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BackButtonTest">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BackButtonTest App</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="backbuttonCtrl as bbc">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
       Some random text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This article will help: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `$locationChangeStart` because that is where you can "prevent" the change from happening.

Logic is basically:

1. Intercept the location change request.
2. Determine if you need to show your modal
3. If so `preventDefault` on the location change ( this will stop the change from happening)
4. Save where the user wanted to go
5. Show your modal
6. If they click 'cancel' forget #4
7. If they click ok, allow #4 to happen.

This link walks through the details of how to do it: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs

Comment: Hi Nix, I did try  $locationChangeStart as you suggested but no luck. Also tried dwahlin example but still not luck. Does someone have a jsfiddle or plnkr example?

Comment: Okay, so I have the developer console open in Chrome, and what I want is to catch the event that is fired when the back button is clicked. This is what is not working. It simply goes back to the previous page without hitting any of the $locationChageStart, $locationChageSuccess, $routeChangeStart, $watch (for location path change).

Further more, I have added the mentioned events in both the controller AND in Run. Neither place catch the event fired when the browser back button is clicked.